# How To Split String by space and store each character or substring in array

Tags: apex, string, array, split

How To Split String by space and store each character or substring in array
I have: String  -   '(1 OR 2) AND 3'
I need in this way:

`String [] filterLogicSplittedbySpace=new String[]{'(', '1', 'OR', '2', ')', 'AND', '3'};`

Please guide.

Answer (score 4):

Usage of `String.split` method doesn't fit your requirements, as you will have `'(1'` first element and `'2)'` third element. Use [String.splitByCharacterType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) method.

> Splits the current String by character type and returns a list of
>   contiguous character groups of the same type as complete tokens.

This will split and extract correct parts of your string. Brackets are split from numbers

```
String str = '(1 OR 2) AND 3';
List<String> groupedResult = str.splitByCharacterType();
List<String> filterLogicSplitbySpace= new List<String>();
for(String sequence :groupedResult){
    if(sequence.isAlphanumeric()){
        filterLogicSplitbySpace.add(sequence);
    } else if(String.isNotBlank(sequence)){
        List<String> brakets = sequence.split('');
        for(String bracket :brakets){
            filterLogicSplitbySpace.add(bracket);
        }
    }
}
System.debug(filterLogicSplitbySpace);
```

Debug result is:

> DEBUG|((, 1, OR, 2, ), AND, 3)

this code also works for more complicated conditions, like `String str = '((1 OR 2) AND 3) OR 4';`

Debug is:

> DEBUG|((, (, 1, OR, 2, ), AND, 3, ), OR, 4)

Answer (score -1):

split(' ') method will do the work.

```
String spl = 'Hello v ivek { } ';
String[] sp2 = spl.split(' ');
System.debug(sp2);
```